# I have to create a 2 dimensional list for a board game with n rows and p columns in a rectangular shape without numpy and GUI

Tags: python, arrays

I succeeded in creating the empty board. But the problem is that I want to display it in a rectangular shape without the use of numpy or any other libraries. I tried the 'join.str' but i cannot manipulate the list afterwards. Is there a way to do it.

Here is the code

```
    n = 3#number of rows
    p = 2#number of columns
    board = []

    def newBoard(n, board, p):
        board = [[0] * p for i in range(n)]
        print(board)

    newBoard(n, board, p)
```

The output of the code is displayed in this form.

[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

The display that i want to obtain should be in this form.

[0,0]

[0,0]

[0,0]

Comment: you shouldn't print everything with one giant print, you have to iterate for each and print in a formatted way separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
n = 3  #number of rows
p = 2  #number of columns

def newBoard(n, board, p):
    board = [[0] * p for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(len(board)):
        print(board[i])

newBoard(n, board, p)

# [0, 0]
# [0, 0]
# [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the rows and print them individually:

```
>>> board = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> for r in board:
...     print(r)
... 
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

---

Or you could convert each row to a `string`, and then join with new-line (`\n`) characters:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(str(r) for r in board))
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

---

Or if you wanted it took look more like that of `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> print('['+'\n '.join(str(r) for r in board)+']')
[[0, 0]
 [0, 0]
 [0, 0]]
```